# pass on vs propagate

Tags: phrases, sentence

can someone help me with the following sentences?

> Pass on this message to your friends.
>
> Propagate this message to your friends.

Does the 2nd one even correct?

"Propagate this message" sounds kind of very weird to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Kind of very weird* sounds at least as weird to me as *Propagate this message*, but if you're comfortable with one I suppose the other won't seem particularly out of place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oxford Dictionaries (online) gives this definition.

*Propagate
2. Spread and promote (an idea, theory, etc.) widely.*
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/

The important word here is 'widely'.

The sentence "Propagate this message." makes perfect sense, especially if the message is or contains an idea rather than simple facts.

However the phrase "to your friends" implies a limited circulation, not a wide one. This is contrary to the definition.

**Conclusion**

"Pass on" is a better verb in this context.

Comment: I would even extend that to the notion that propagation implies such a wide spread that one person can not be the source. A friend may HELP propagate a message by passing it their friends, but a friend won't propagate it all on their own. The hope is that the result is a Wella Balsam commercial. I told two friends and they told two friends and so on and so on and so on....